# How Can I Update user-data on Openstack?

Tags: openstack, cloud-init

I have a bunch of openstack VMs running on Grizzly.  I need to change their domain which is currently managed by cloud-init.  How do I update the user-data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I've found to update user-data on existing VMs is to modify the database contents.  I detailed the steps for mysql here:

http://www.asmatteringofit.com/blog/2015/4/18/updating-user-data-for-existing-openstack-vms